# How to search all the articles that have the same (or at least one) tag with the current page?

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet

I found

```
TaggedTheSameAsCurrentPage|SxaTags
```

and

```
TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags
```

that is similar to what I need. However it doesn't return any results.
I couldn't find much information about it on the internet. 
Do I need any further setting?

Thanks you
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in Content Editor. Those new tokens can be used in search scopes. You will see results on a page/api response (https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/search/extend_search)

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I used it in ItemQuery, and applied it to the PageList. No result at all. Those token should not be used for the whole site

Comment: As @Alan suggested please create the Search scope and try it.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak how can a search scope be used with a page listing rendering?  Or its not possible to use sxa tokens to drive the items listed?

Comment: I have literally the same thing and it doesn't work at all.